# how to set jquery autocomplete by id and not by label

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

hi all i got a jquery autocomplete with source of the form:

```
var source = [
              {"label":"item 1", "value":1}, 
              {"label":"item 2", "value":2}, 
              {"label":"item 3", "value":3}];
```

all i want to do is set the autocomplete to show let say "item 1" if i give him the value 1
and show "item 2" if i give it the value 2.

all i see is option to set the auto complete by label like this:

```
$("#myAutoCompleteID").val("item 1") ;
```

i want to set the auto complete by value ... something like:

```
$("#myAutoCompleteID").setValByValue(1)
```

any help?

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you write a small function your self

```
function GetLabelByValue(val){
 $.each(function(i,v){
 if(v.value === val)
  {
   return v.label;
  }
 });
}
$("#myAutoCompleteID").val(GetLabelByValue(1)) ;
```

Comment: don't forget to upvote or mark as ans if this helped. this might also help others coming to this site